# NHibernate.ISession.Flush() is taking a long time after a Delete()-Operation

Tags: nhibernate, flush

In my application I would like to clear/empty a table (which is the only one) in my SQLite-DB.
I am programming in C#. _session is of type NHibernate.ISession. Here is my code:

string queryFmt = "FROM {0}";
string query = String.Format(queryFmt, typeName);
_session.Delete(query);
_session.Flush();

My example-DB consists of over 5000 entries (the s3db-file is about 750KB big). The Flush()-Method needs more than 6 minutes. (When I execute the delete-operation in the SQLite Administrator it takes less than a second.)

How can I empty the table faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ExecuteUpdate on a hql query 
Here's an example:

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{

    String hqlDelete = string.Format("delete {0} t",typename);
    int deletedEntities = session.CreateQuery( hqlDelete ).ExecuteUpdate();
    session.Close();
}
```

Comment: one minor change: it's "session.CreateQuery..." and not "hqlDelete.CreateQuery..."

Answer (score 0):

If you set nhib to show_sql=true in the config, what sql is output?

---

After your response, you can see that nhib is taking so long because it's not bulk deleting the rows.

Ayende has a post explaining it [here.](http://ayende.com/blog/1294/bulk-data-operations-using-nhibernate)

Comment: for _session.Delete(...): NHibernate: select logentry0_.Id as Id22_, logentry0_.Message as Message22_, logentry0_.Type as Type22_, logentry0_.Category as Category22_, logentry0_.DateCreated as DateCrea5_22_, logentry0_.Level as Level22_ from Log logentry0_ 

 ============ for _session.Flush(): NHibernate: DELETE FROM Log WHERE Id = @p0;@p0 = 1 NHibernate: DELETE FROM Log WHERE Id = @p0;@p0 = 2 ... NHibernate: DELETE FROM Log WHERE Id = @p0;@p0 = 99 NHibernate: DELETE FROM Log WHERE Id = @p0;@p0 = 100